# about loop and suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

I am trying to understand the following construction. $X$ is a pointed CW complex.
Define $Q(X) := hocolim_{n} \Omega^n \Sigma^n (X)$.
Using the loop-suspension adjunction, we get maps like $X \to \Omega \Sigma X \to \Omega \Sigma \Omega \Sigma X \to ...$.
Why is $ (\Omega \Sigma)^n = \Omega^n \Sigma^n$? Or, how exactly do we get maps for the colimit mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any space $Y$, you get a nice map $\eta_Y: Y \to \Omega \Sigma Y$. Let $Y = \Sigma X$ and apply $\Omega$ to the map $\eta_{\Sigma X}$ to get $\Omega \eta_{\Sigma X}: \Omega (\Sigma X) \to \Omega (\Omega \Sigma (\Sigma X)) = \Omega^2 \Sigma^2 X$. Iterate to get the maps forming the directed system.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!